# Why isn't my report changing the sorting based on the input radio button being toggled?

Tags: sorting, vbscript, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that I want sorted differently based on 2 radio buttons (boolean input parameter). If the `true` radio button is selected, sort by `Sum(Fields!plannedPallets.Value)`, otherwise sort by `Sum(Fields!lbrHrsPlanned.Value)`. However, I'm having trouble with the syntax to use in the expression for sorting the group.

**This is what I've tried:**

```
="Sum(Fields!" & IIF(Parameters!PalletSorting.Value = True, "plannedPallets", "lbrHrsPlanned") & ".Value)"
```

...but this has no effect on the sorting. My guess is because I'm returning a string here when it's expecting something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was simply:

```
=IIF(Parameters!PalletSorting.Value = True, Sum(Fields!plannedPallets.Value), Sum(Fields!lbrHrsPlanned.Value))
```